# Plesk only_full_group_by error

Tags: mysql, plesk, plesk-onyx

Version: Plesk Onyx v17.8.11_build1708180301.19
OS:     Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

In my logs I have this error:

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1055 Expression #7 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause
>   and contains nonaggregated column 'base.count_traffic.type' which is
>   not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by' in

mysql -V -> `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

And SQL_MODE settings are:   `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Same settings and same Pleask version on another server and all is working, but on this, no!

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [sql_mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html) behavior in MySQL. You need to change this parameter globally and on session and remove `only_full_group_by`:

```
SET GLOBAl sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

And on session:

```
SET session sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Note that for existing connections in the database this will not have any effect. The configuration will be applied only for new connections. If needed, you can edit your `my.cnf` and restart the database. Here is an example:

```
[mysqld]
sql-mode='NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
```

Comment: any idea @ViniciusGrippa

Comment: Do you have the query? Please share the table structure as well from all tables involved in the query using this command:

`SHOW CREATE TABLE <TABLE_NAME>;`

And your MySQL version:
`select @@version;`

I'll perform some tests.

Comment: http://codepad.org/37MfEadO  I have a procedure in database that I call from a cron! It is very strange because on other server is working with same settings! mysql version: 5.7.22

Comment: I don't see any problem with the procedures @DigitalBeko, but I would like to check these statuses:

`show session variables like '%sql_mode%';`
`show global variables like '%sql_mode%';`

I suspect that the default configuration might be override.